# How can I set the tab width in a monaco editor instance?

Tags: javascript, typescript, monaco-editor

I would like to **set the indentation width** (in spaces) in an instance of the [**monaco editor**](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor).

So far, I've been able to customize many options by passing in any of the [`IEditorOptions`](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/master/website/playground/monaco.d.ts.txt#L1048) during initialization. These options can also be customized later using the `updateOptions` method on an editor instance, as visible in the following example:

```js
// Many settings can be applied at initialization
var editor = monaco.editor.create(
  document.getElementById("editor"), {
    language: "html",
    value: "<p>Hello World!</p>",
});

// ... they can also be changed later ...
editor.updateOptions({
  lineNumbers: true,
})

// ... however, tabSize is not among the settings that can be modified --
// the following has no effect:
editor.updateOptions({
  tabSize: 2,
})
```

However, the [**`tabSize`**](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.formattingoptions.html#tabsize) setting is **not defined in this interface**, but rather a seperate [`FormattingOptions`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.formattingoptions.html) interface, for which I haven't been able to find a binding (a code search finds [only the interface definition](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=FormattingOptions)).

**Can you help me adjust this setting?** My guess is that I'm misunderstanding the (otherwise excellent) editor documentation, so any help in navigating it would be extremely helpful.

As always, any ideas and hints are hugely appreciated. **Thank you very much for considering this question!**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer has just been discussed in a corresponding [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/270#issuecomment-273263768). The trick is not to update the options on the editor directly, but on the underlying model. To extend the snipped above:

```js
const editor = monaco.editor.create(
  document.getElementById("editor"), {
    language: "html",
    value: "<p>Hello World!</p>",
});

editor.getModel().updateOptions({ tabSize: 2 })
```

This works for me (™) in the [Monaco Playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#creating-the-editor-hello-world).

All credit for this goes to the monaco devs — I absolutely love their editor, and this improves it even further.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore, getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`

Comment: The edit queue is full, but replace the ID "editor" with "container" and it should work.

Comment: Note that this may not fully answer the question though, as this sets the _visual_ tab size, as opposed to using actual spaces.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't been able to figure out how to set a global `tabSize` option either, however I did manage to set the option specifically for **HTML**:

`editor.languages.html.htmlDefaults.setOptions({ tabSize: 2 });`

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to set the tab width for the first time, you can do it in the constructor using the `tabSize` option:

```js
monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
    value: "function hello() {\n\talert('Hello world!');\n}",
    language: 'javascript',
    tabSize: 2,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will create two models that you can control independently

```
const markdownModel = monaco.editor.createModel("", "markdown");
const styleModel = monaco.editor.createModel("", "css");
```

You can now access the models using `monaco.editor.getModels()`
which returns an array, so you could do `monaco.editor.getModels()[0]` 
to access your first model, or even easier is access each model by 
its variable name. Such as

```
markdownModel.updateOptions({ tabSize: 2 });
styleModel.updateOptions({ tabSize: 4 });
```

And as a bonus, you can create two seperate editors 
using the two seperate models by creating it and linking it to independent
DOM elements.

```
monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("markdown-editor"), {
  model: markdownModel,
  wordWrap: "wordWrapColumn",
  wordWrapColumn: 60,
  wordWrapMinified: true,
  wrappingIndent: "indent",
  lineNumbers: "off",
  scrollBeyondLastLine: false
});

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("style-editor"), {
  model: styleModel,
  wordWrap: "wordWrapColumn",
  wordWrapColumn: 80,
  wordWrapMinified: true,
  wrappingIndent: "indent",
});
```